# Windows R CMD check top-level files: (README) [WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, r-package, github-actions

I have activated GitHub Action to CI for R on Win, OSX, and Linux. On Windows only happen the following warning (which is turned into an error).

```
* checking top-level files ... WARNING

Conversion of 'README.md' failed:

[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.

  Please specify either 'title' or 'pagetitle' in the metadata,

  e.g. by using --metadata pagetitle="..." on the command line.

  Falling back to 'README'
```

[here](https://github.com/UBESP-DCTV/covid19ita/pull/62/checks?check_run_id=594799232) the full report.

It seems it is called by CMD check directly, hence I cannot change the call to pandoc.

On the other hand, I tried to include a pandoc argument into the `README.Rmd` header as it was suggested [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rmarkdown-document-format-requires-a-nonempty-title-element/36774):

```
output:
  github_document: 
    pandoc_args: "--number-offset=1,0"
    toc: true
pagetitle: covid19ita
```

It has no effect.

NOTE: I would not remove `error_on = "warning"` from CMD check.

What can I do to make the test pass on win too?

Comment: I think R CMD check doesn't see your .Rmd file, it only sees the .md file.  Did the `pagetitle:` line make through to there?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the `R CMD check` does not see the `.Rmd` (ie it is included in `.Rbuiltignore`). I knit the `.Rmd` at every change. `pagetitle:` seems to have no effect at all to the `.md` file

Comment: Your title looks quite strange; I see `title: "\`{covid19ita}\` <img src='man/figures/logo-laims.jpg' align='right' height='120' /><img src='man/figures/logo-ubep.png' align='right' height='120' />"` in the Rmd file.  Maybe simplify it to plain text?

Comment: Use simple text does not change: https://github.com/UBESP-DCTV/covid19ita/pull/62/checks?check_run_id=595253618

It is also strange that there R3.5 passed and R3.6 no, while [here](https://github.com/UBESP-DCTV/covid19ita/runs/595253631?check_suite_focus=true) (old title) it was the opposite... I'm start to think it could be related to the following error of fatching badge from AppVeyor... now I try to deactivate it

Comment: The same happens for a missing badge in codecov [here](https://github.com/UBESP-DCTV/covid19ita/pull/62/checks?check_run_id=595523293)

So, I think the problem relates to the ability to fetch badges

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main issue is related to the inability to fetch badges in the rendered document. That could be seen [here](https://github.com/UBESP-DCTV/covid19ita/pull/62/checks?check_run_id=595253618) (pass for R3.5 but not for R3.6), or [here](https://github.com/UBESP-DCTV/covid19ita/runs/595253631?check_suite_focus=true) (pass for R3.6 but not for R3.5), and [here](https://github.com/UBESP-DCTV/covid19ita/pull/62/checks?check_run_id=595523293) (where the missing badge is no more the AppVeyor one but the CodeCov one).

So my current solution is to be sure all the badges are ready *before* or change *after* the check action takes place (eg using only gh-action).